# Extjs 5.1 Item click not fired with charts with one item

Tags: javascript, charts, click, listener, extjs5

I have a very simple chart (a pie chart), with a store containing 3 items. I listen to itemClick event, and display the name of the slice of the pie clicked in a label. My problem is, when the pie only contains 1 slice, the click event is not fired when I click on it.

Here a simple and detailed sencha fiddle that explains every thing: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i52

And if you're lazy to click here the same code  !

**Stores:**

```
var storeA = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'value'],
    data: [
        {"name": "A-0", "value": 18.34},
        {"name": "A-1", "value": 2.67},
        {"name": "A-2", "value": 1.90}
    ]
});

var storeB = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'value'],
    data: [
        {"name": "B-0", "value": 18.34}
    ]
});
```

**Chart:**

```
var pie = Ext.create('Ext.chart.PolarChart', {
    title: 'Test',
    animation: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    store: storeA,

    plugins: {
        ptype: 'chartitemevents',
        moveEvents: true
    },

    listeners: {
        itemclick: function(series, item, event, eOpts) {
            label.setText('Item clicked: ' + item.record.get('name'));
        }
    },

    legend: {
        docked: 'bottom'
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        angleField: 'value',
        colors: ["#9aff4f", "#35b4e3", "#ffb400"],
        label: {
            field: 'name',
            display: 'inside'
        }
    }]
});
```

**Button to change pie store and label to display clicked slice:**

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click to change the pie store',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    margin: '10 10 10 63',
    handler: function() {
        if (pie.getStore() == storeA) {
            pie.bindStore(storeB);
        }
        else {
            pie.bindStore(storeA);
        }
    }
});

var label = Ext.create('Ext.form.Label', {
    text: 'Item clicked: ',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Thanks a lot for you help :) :) :) !!

Comment: It seems to be a bug: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?297315-Mouse-events-don-t-work-on-Pie-charts-%28sencha-chart%29-with-only-one-slice-visibile&p=1085793

Comment: Yes you're right, it seem to be a know bug, thanks a lot :) !

Answer (score 0):

This workaround solve:

```
listeners: {

render:function(el){

    el.getEl().on('click',function()
    {
       var cnf = el.store.config.data[0];
       var name = cnf.name;
       var value = cnf.value;
    console.log(name)
    console.log(value)
    })
}
}
```